# how to extarct keywords or tags from the file content

Tags: java, tags, metadata, keyword, apache-tika

I have some files of different formats(Html,PDF,doc,epub), using apache tika and java i have extracted metadata and stored it into mongo db, now my aim is to extract keywords or tags from the file content and add it to one of the metadata fields, is it possible with Apache tika or if not please suggest me the way to do it?

my mongodb field(example)

```
{"Filename":"PHP Book.pdf","Author":"John" ,"Description":"This is my PHP Book"} 
{"Filename":"Java Book.html" ,"Author":"Paul" ,"Description":"This is my JAVA Book"}
{"Filename":".NET Book.doc" ,"Author":"James" ,"Description":"This is my .NET Book"}
```

now i want to add another field which contain content tags or keywords,it should look like as follows(example)

```
{"Filename":"PHP Book.pdf","Author":"John" ,"Description":"This is my PHP Book", "keywords":["PHP","PDF","BOOK"]} 
{"Filename":"Java Book.html" ,"Author":"Paul" ,"Description":"This is my JAVA Book","keywords":["JAVA","html","BOOK"]}
{"Filename":".NET Book.doc" ,"Author":"James" ,"Description":"This is my .NET Book",    "keywords":[".NET","doc"]}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the keywords and tags in the document metadata, for those file formats that support storing it? (Tika will already give you that!)

Comment: I am extracting only metadata tags using tika. if i have content as "Hi hello hi hello welcome" i want to extract Hi, hello as tags from content(frequently occuring words), is this possible with tika?

Comment: Tika will happily give you the text of the document. You'll need to use something else to calculate the commonly occurring words, strip out ones that are too common etc